# I can't handle the error with try-catch block in Dart

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart. I was trying to learn how try-catch works by creating a silly error.
But unfortunately, it seems my catch block is not been reached. It's just throwing an unhandled error. Why it's happening?
This is the code-

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  try {
    int x = 44 / 0;
    print(x);
  } catch (e) {
    print('It is an infinity error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error are a static compile error from the type system since you are trying to assign a `double` to a `int` variable. This types of errors cannot be catch since they will happen before the program are even attempt running.

If you want to do this division but want a `int` as the result, you can use the [`~/`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) operator:

So this works where the exception are triggered:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  try {
    int x = 44 ~/ 0;
    print(x); // <-- not executed
  } catch (e) {
    print('It is an infinity error'); // <-- this is printed
  }
}
```

You can also assign the result to a `double` value. This, however, does not work as you expect since `double` will not fail but instead represent the value as `Infinity`:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  try {
    double x = 44 / 0;
    print(x); // Prints: Infinity
  } catch (e) {
    print('It is an infinity error'); // <-- not executed
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

But my question was how can I activate the catch block? I know it will be an error. But the catch block is not executed It's giving me an unhandled error. I am not trying to fix it My question was how to handle the error & run the catch block.

Comment: Please don't use answers as a way to comment. Use the comment feature on a given answer if you have questions.

Comment: I have also updated my answer with some explanation of the reason why you cannot catch the error since it is a compile error which happens before Dart even attempt running your program.